# PHP templating for header and footer?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm making a website with multiple pages with About info, Projects, Events etc.

My first question is, how can I include my nav bar, header and footer to be in all of the html files without copying the full code for each of them? 
My second question is, how should the html structure look in the separate header/footer files so I can include them in my pages html's?

If you mention PHP as a solution, please point me to some link/tutorial for the process.

Comment: create an HTML of header and footer and use include('header.html');

Comment: PHP can definitely help you. Most websites detailing the basics of PHP will teach you how to `include` or `require` a header / footer on every page. Have you tried doing a simple search on such resources?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tried with PHP, but the code phrases in Brackets (my code editor) remained grey and not functional. I will try again with your advices.

Answer (score 7):

If you use php files you could do something like this:

index.php:

```
<? 
    include("header.php");
?>

    //page content

<?
    include("footer.php")
?>
```

header.php:

```
<head>
    //head
</head>
<body>
```

footer.php:

```
<footer>
    //footer
</footer>
</body>
```

In the header.php you could put the  tags etc.
In every page you could just include these files than

Comment: I would strongly recommend adding the footer to your body, as it makes no sence keeping it outside

Comment: The footer could be the same on every page. So it could be useful sometimes

Comment: Thanks Wouter. I'am not using server side at the moment. So, another way would be to literally copy and paste the same header/footer code to every html file I make for every page?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: ooh I didn't know. Would change it :p

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make three files **navbar.php, header.php** and **footer.php** which contains their code separately.

Now in your each web pages place the below code.

```
include('header.php'); //Your website header code will be load from header.php
include('navbar.php'); //Your website navbar code will be load from navbar.php
include('footer.php');//Your website footer code will be load from footer.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with AngularJS. If you do not want to use server side scripting 
http://www.w3schools.com/angular/

```
<body ng-app="">

<div ng-include="'header.htm'"></div>
     Your page goes here
```

```
</body>
```

do not forget to add AngularJS library or you can use cdn.

Answer (score 0):

You can create specific files for header and footer and require them in the pages you need them.

```
require 'footer.php'
require 'header.php'
```