# Site rebuilt on each single page, how to change it?

Tags: html, web

I have a site where every single page is the same as the one except the central `<div>`, the site menu is on each page and every time to add something I have to add it to each single page, there is a way to add something to just edit a single file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have PHP set up and enabled, you can store everything except to the body page in a PHP file (such as header.php) and just include it on every page.

header.php

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

home.php

```
<body>
    <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
    <p>Other content here</p>
</body>
```

Some more answers: [Including header/footer on every page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35769695/including-header-footer-on-every-page)

Comment: i fail the first time to write the answer is not Body but is Div, its the same? i need to import the link of .css/.jquery/.js file on single file or just the first one?

Answer (score 0):

Yes their is but it's not done with HTML. It's done with a server-side language like PHP. You could use PHP includes to include snippits of code to be included in every single page so when you want to update a snipit of code, it would simply go to that one file and update it and it would update for every single page. Here is the documentation for that. http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php